# Double-click on one Excel worksheet that filters another worksheet on the double-clicked value

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets:

1. "Summary" - Containing customer information, and
2. "Transactions" - Containing customer transaction data (multiple rows) assigned to a unique customer identifier.

What I'd like to do is be able to double-click on the unique customer identifier in Sheet1 - Summary which would then filter the data in Sheet2 transactions.

The tables have no names and are sitting in the sheets as data. I've tired using the following code which has been listed as solutions for similar questions but, keep getting a runtime error '9' message.

Hope somebody can help this beginner.

```
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    'amend the SheetName above and below and make sure your table name is correct too
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Based on what I understand from your question, the table you want to filter is in Sheet2 so that what you should have: `Worksheets("Sheet2")...`

Answer (score 0):

If your Tables “*have no names*” then they’re probably not Tables but just ranges of data.  As such, you’d have problems with your `.ListObjects()`.

If you apply the following code as a Private Sub on Sheet1 in the VBA Editor, and assuming your ‘table’ of data on Sheet2 starts in `A1` and `A` is the column you want to filter on, then this should work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.EnableEvents = False
cancel = True

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
 MsgBox "No valid filter value selected"
 GoTo GetOut
End If

   Sheet2.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & ActiveCell.Value
   Application.Goto Sheet2.Range("A1")

GetOut:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End Sub
```